# Error occurs only while loading pdf (iText) in Firefox

Tags: firefox, pdf, itext, pdf.js

Error occurs only while loading pdf (iText) in Firefox. If downloaded, it is fine.

Can anyone help me?

Firefox browser verion: 35
Warning: Unsupported feature "unknown"
Error: Invalid XRef stream

Comment: Show us the PDF. It could be one of two things: (1.) you're using an old iText version and there's an error in the cross-reference stream that is fixed by Adobe Reader, or (2.) the PDF is correct, but you're hitting a limitation of pdf.js (which is the PDF viewer shipped with Firefox).

Comment: my pdf size is 106kb. may be i will try by replacing new version.Could you tell how ican check max size of pdf.js in browser. Thanks for your suggestion @Bruno Lowagie

Comment: 106 kb is very small. pdf.js should be able to deal with that. Are you sure you meant to type kb?

Comment: pdf size:106 kb and error occur in pdf.worker.js file and my iText version is 5.3.5

Comment: That information doesn't help. It is the PDF we need to see. Have you done a PDF syntax check in Adobe Acrobat? If it passes that test, the problem is with pdf.js, not with iText.

Comment: PDF opened successfully in Adobe Acrobat. PDF document is private one.

Comment: Have you used "Preflight" in Acrobat and done a PDF syntax check? If that check showed "No errors", then the problem isn't caused by iText, but you are facing a problem with pdf.js (the default PDF viewer in Firefox). You should tag your question accordingly (I'll do that for you).

Comment: *PDF document is private one* - then similarly produce another PDF with test data which shows the same oddity and share that file.